# AngularJS form to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am learning AngualrJS and am a little confused as to how to how to create a json from the form input data. I am using ng-click when the button is clicked to submit data. Not sure if this is the right way to do it.

I was trying to use this to create the json...

```
$http({method: 'POST',
    url: 'customers.json',
    data: $scope.customer,
}).success(function (data) {
// handle
});
```

My plunker is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/UiaG8U?p=info

Comment: Looks like you just forgot to inject $http into your controller. Other than that it looks fine. You can also do $http.post(url,data).success(). It is a little cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: +1 for use of Plunker.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you needed to pass in $http to the scope of the controller.

Comment: I added $http to the scope of the controller like so `customerApp.controller('customerCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {` but customers.json still is empty, am i missing something?

Comment: Which browser are you using? It worked for me in FF, but in Chrome, I couldn't see the variables. I think it's because there's a 404 on the URL.

Comment: Try using FF and Firebug.

Comment: How can I tell if it is working or not, maybe I am misunderstanding something. Should the scope data be inserted into the file customers.json?